# React: TypeError: this.props.courses.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, redux

I can't understand why I can't `.map` an array.

this is the code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { fetchCourses } from "../../actions";

class Courses extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchCourses();
  }

  render() {
    console.log("this.props.payload.courses ", this.props.courses);
    const courses = this.props.courses.map(course => {
      return (
        <tr>
          <td>{course.coursename}</td>

          <td>{course.coursetype ? "yes" : "no"}</td>

          <td>{course.courseweeklyhours}</td>

          <td>
            <button>הסר</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      );
    });

    return (
      <div>
        Courses
        {courses}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  // console.log('state ', state);

  return {
    courses: state.courses
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { fetchCourses }
)(Courses);
```

this is the result from the console.log (first line after the render)

[image]

I have two questions

1. why do I get this error:
   TypeError: this.props.courses.map is not a function
   [image]
2. why the console.log `this.props.payload.courses` is loaded twice?

Comment: By any chance, have you initialised courses to be an object in reducer

Comment: yes, it is an oblect, https://www.screencast.com/t/Qob6kUmCVt

Comment: I i do it as an array I see output but I see this result
https://www.screencast.com/t/aOBOjKdF
It is like I have an array with two arrays inside it

Comment: I added an answer, please check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to correct your reducer implementation. Your console output suggests that `this.props.courses` is an object with one key as `courses` that is an array and hence you are not able to map over `this.props.courses`.

Since your reducer seems to be named with `courses` in `combinedReducer` and your initial state is an array, you should return the updated state also as an array instead of an object

```
export default (state = [], action) {
    switch(action.type){
        case FETCH_COURSES: {
            return action.payload.data
        }
        ...
    }

}
```